# What does the fieldset form attribute really do?

Tags: html, relationship, fieldset

I am not sure what the meaning of the `fieldset` `form` attribute is. MDN says:

> This attribute takes the value of the id attribute of a `<form>` element you want the `<fieldset>` to be **part of**, even if it is not inside the form. Please note that usage of this is confusing — if you want the  elements inside the `<fieldset>` to be associated with the form, you need to use the form attribute directly on those elements.

which means that the `fieldset`'s fields are not automatically included in the `form` (you have to put the `form` attribute on each of them if you want them to be), but the `fieldset` is *part of* the form. What does that actually mean?

[The spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#the-fieldset-element) says:

> The form attribute is used to explicitly associate the fieldset element with its **form owner**.

And the *form owner* is [linked](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#form-owner) to the note

> A form-associated element can have a **relationship** with a form element, which is called the element's form owner.

Where it ends without any explanation what *relationship* is supposed to be. If you are a `fieldset`, could you describe in well defined terms what it feels like to be in a relationship with `form`?

**Code to verify**

```
<form id="myform">
    <input name="happy" value="happy">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>

<fieldset form="myform">
    <input name="unhappy" value="unhappy">
</fieldset>
```

The `unhappy` input is not sent with the form.

Comment: it makes the whole fieldset linked to that form, so that form is doing the submitting of the inputs within that fieldset, just like you can do the opposite for [input fields -> form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form). it's pretty self-explanatory...

Comment: @vsync it does not - as I noted, MDN warns about it and as I tested, the inputs within are not sent.

Comment: I think I understand what you ask (you have a field set outside a form, try to submit the form, the content of the input elements in the field set is not sent), but the question is worded quite confusingly. Perhaps you can add an example HTML or something?

Comment: @JanTuroň - I think the relationship in question is *semantic*. I do find it odd that form elements within a `<fieldset form="x">...</fieldset>` aren't automatically included with the form, though. There wouldn't seem to be a lot of point in a semantic relationship involving forms and form elements (in the fieldset) if those elements aren't included when the form is submitted. In fact, I'd argue such semantics are problematic at best... :-)

Comment: One obvious thing it does is to append the <fieldset> in <form>'s `.elements`. How useful is this? Hem... not my area, but yeah can't really tell... Maybe someone thought *certainly some users will want to do `document.forms[x].elements[y].elements[z]` to access an element that is not gonna be sent by `x`*. Oh, and it's been proposed already that this attribute gets inherited to inner form-associated elements: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/3611

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's confusing. I made a polyfill. Comments and suggestions are welcome.

```
function control() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll("FIELDSET[form]");
  
  var getter = function () {
    return this.getAttribute("form"); 
  };
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var nameForm = items[i].getAttribute("form");
    var subs = items[i].children;
    for(var j = 0; j < subs.length; j++) {
      if(subs[j].tagName == 'BUTTON' || subs[j].tagName == 'INPUT' || subs[j].tagName == 'FIELDSET' || subs[j].tagName == 'OUTPUT' || subs[j].tagName == 'SELECT' || subs[j].tagName == 'TEXTAREA') { 
        subs[j].setAttribute("form",nameForm);
      }
    }
    Object.defineProperty(items[i], 'form', {
      get: getter
    });
  }
}
window.addEventListener("load",control,true);
```

Comment: The question is about what is the meaning of the form attribute on the fieldset, not how do I pass the form attribute to inputs in the fieldset. It is partially cleared in Kaiido's comment.